# User input names that edit cells to then be called upon later calculation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a script in sheets that takes user input for their name then places that name into a sister sheet where I am using the cells to create a dropdown menu in another sheet. I am new to writing scripts on sheets, and am unable to get this to work

```
function promptUserAge() {
  // Prompt for the value
  var age = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Please enter the age.").getResponseText();

  // Get the sheet that you want store the value in and set the value in the cell B3
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Patient Information").getRange("B3").setValue(age);
}
```

i found this elsewhere on overflow but i couldnt get it to work.
i also dont know how to then import this script into my sheet

Comment: The script you provided works with no changes.  It's not clear to me what else you wish to do with it.  If you want to run this as a Custom Function the you should read {Using Google Spreadsheet service in Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced) You will see that custom functions cannot write to other cells. And they must return something

Comment: @Cooper I see now that it does what was intended and i changed it to do what I need however, I still cant figure out a way to have it edit multiple cells in B. if I want it to edit the cells sequentially down from B3 how could i change the script to do so?  In matlab I would use an if statement and a loop to validate the input. But I am not sure how to do it here. Sorry if my previous question was so Beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
function promptUserAge() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const resp = ui.prompt("Please enter the age.",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    let age = resp.getResponseText();
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
    sh.getRange(getColumnHeight(2,sh,ss) + 1,2).setValue(age)
  }
}

function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
  //const h = Utilities.formatString('col: %s len: %s', col, rcA.length - s);
  //Logger.log(h);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(h).setWidth(150).setHeight(100), 'Col Length')
}
```